# quickselect algorithm

Tags: c++, median

when i run  following code for quickselection

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
const int n = 15;
int b[100];
int btotal=0;
int c[100];
int ctotal=0;

void read(int a[],int size){
    for (int i=1; i<=15; i++) cin >> a[i];
}

int quickselect(int a[], int k)
{
    int r = 1 + rand()%(n-1);
    int pivot = a[r];
    for (int i=1; i<=n; i++) {
        if (a[i] < pivot) {
            b[i] = a[i];
            ++btotal;
        }

        if (a[i] > pivot) {
            c[i] = a[i];
            ++ctotal;
        }  
    }

    if (k <= btotal) quickselect(b,k);
    if (k > (n-ctotal)) return quickselect(c, k - (n-ctotal));        

    return pivot;          
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int a[n];
    cout <<" enter contents of array " << endl;
    read(a, n);
    quickselect(a, 6);
    //system("PAUSE");
    //return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    return 0;
}

1 4 2 3 5 7 6 9 8 10 13 12 11 15 14
```

i have got runtime error,i think here it is problem related with  indexing,but can't find where,please help me

Comment: I guess you mean "quicksort" ?

Comment: no no quickselect,but  i  guessed main problem with this code

Comment: Just a hint, when choosing pivot value for quicksort, you're better of selecting the median of three. This will make the algoritm likley pick a good pivot value. If you choose a random element, and that element happends to be the lowest or highest value the algoritm will be very slow. I'll get back to you if I find out whats wrong with the code

Comment: i dont know by using  code,how find median of three

Answer (score 2):

You are writing outside the bounds of you array `a`.

`int a[15]` will allocate room for 15 integers, with index spanning from `a[0]` to `a[14]`. You are current reading/writing to offset `[1]` to (and including) `[15]` which is wrong.

---

**minimum changes required**

```
void
read (int a[],int size)
{
  for (int i=0; i < 15; i++) // CHANGE TO
    ...
}

...

int
quickselect(int a[],int  k)
{
  ...

  for (int i=0; i < n; i++) { // CHANGE TO

  ...
}
```

Comment: yes   @refp thanks very much,i can use 1  indexed array,but i think about one thing,when i   call  recursively  quickselect,don't i overwrite already existed  arrays? i mean c and b

Comment: @dato don't forget to mark the answer as *accepted* to aid future readers to see if the problem has been solved or not. Regarding your question about "overwrite already existed arrays", that is a topic better discussed in a new thread.